# App availability date for app in development?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I´m going to add Game Center features to my application so I need to create an "App" in iTunes connect first.

In the settings for "Availability Date", how should I set this up if I have no idea when the game will be ready for launch?

Do I need to create another app i iTunes connect when it´s complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any availability date, and you can change it every time you want. For example, Jan 1st 2014. Then, after submit set the date to the real release date.

IF you have an uploaded & approved by apple binary AND a past availability date, your app will be on store.

Comment: You're welcome! I had the same problem with my first app @marsrover